# asp:GridView -> asp:TemplateField Calling Public Method Not Available Inside Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've been migrating aspx pages to a new ASP.NET WebApplication. I use the calling of public method inside `Gridview` quite a bit. But my inpage reference can't see the code behind method.

I'm using framework 4.7.2. I get the

> ERROR: CS0103 The name 'GetReturnedString' does not exist in the
>   current context

All my other server controls are accessible, jut not these public defined methods. No luck in Google :(

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>                                
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Literal ID="ltlString" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# GetReturnedString(Eval("FieldExample1").ToString())%>'>
                </asp:Literal>
            </ItemTemplate>               
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

My example code behind looks like this:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public string GetReturnedString(string fieldval1)
    {
        var outValue = "Something";
        return outValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to add GetReturnedString to all of the FieldExample1 rows? I guess your Gridview has more than one row.

Comment: Correct, the public method in my code behind .cs as shown above as example normally worked and would run for each row. Now I get The name 'GetReturnedString' does not exist in the current context even though I made it public method in the code-behind of the aspx page when trying to build the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would DataBind the GridView from the code behind page and add the something to the datatable column before databind.
Then the aspx page would have:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <Columns>                                
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Literal ID="ltlString" runat="server" 
                                 Text='<%# (Eval("FieldExample1").ToString()) %>'>
                    </asp:Literal>
                </ItemTemplate>               
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

The code behind file:

```
    DataTable dtB = new DataTable();
    dtB = //get the datatable from your data source

    if (dtB != null && dtB.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow drB in dtB.Rows)
            {
                drB["FieldExample1"] = GetReturnedString() + drB["FieldExample1"];
            }
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = dtB;
        GridView1.DataBind();

   public string GetReturnedString()
   {
      var outValue = "Something ";
      return outValue;
   }
```

Have a look. You can do the formatting, etc.
At least it works on my test page and should work for you too, I hope.